# Is it possible to change CSS with a jQuery scripts that's loaded externally?

Tags: jquery, css, external

I have SVG code on my index page and I load a popup with the .load method with some html and a close button. When I click the close button within the popup I want to change the fill attribute of a SVG element on the main page but I don't think it will be possible. The external file that's loaded is in a subfolder.

```
//code on main page to open the popup
$("#isl1").click(function () {
    $("#opdracht").slideDown({
        duration: 300,
        easing: "easeOutBack"
    })
    .load("opdrachten/opdracht1.html");
});


//close button on external html file
$("#close").click(function () {
    $("#opdracht").slideUp({
        duration: 1000,
        easing: "easeInBack"
    })
    $(this).find('.st7').css('fill', '#ffffff');
});
```

There are no errors but the fill isn't changed. When I use the code on the main page it works but I was expecting it wouldn't work on a loaded page. I'm hoping someone will point me in the right direction of how to go about this.

Comment: `$(this)` is what element inside the click handler for #close ?

Comment: Honestly, I wasn't sure but I changed this into the SVG ID and now it works, thanks so much!

Comment: `this` in that context refers to #close element and `.st7` is not inside that element?

Answer (score 0):

I changed $(this) into $('#my_svg_id') and that did the trick!